# Radio Buttons are not getting checked on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, radio-button, radio-group

This is my HTML. It is working perfectly fine on browsers for windows but it is not working on mobile devices both Android and iPhone.

```
<div>
    <label onclick="javascript:;" for="PaytoDriver" style="padding-right:5px; font-style: italic;font-size: 24px">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" style="" id="PaytoDriver" value="1" checked="checked">
        Pay to Driver </label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>
    <label onclick="javascript:;" for="PaybyPhone" style="padding-right:5px; font-style: italic;font-size: 24px">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" style="" id="PaybyPhone" value="2">
        Pay by Phone </label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>
    <label onclick="javascript:;" for="Paypal" style="padding-right:5px; font-style: italic;font-size: 24px">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" style="" id="Paypal" value="3">
        Paypal </label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>
    <label onclick="javascript:;" for="CardPayment" style="padding-right:5px; font-style: italic;font-size: 24px">
        <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" style="" id="CardPayment" value="4">
        Card Payment </label>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <br>
</div>
```

**Update**

Users are not able to select any of the radio buttons. not getting checked.

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: trying removing `onclick="javascript:;"`

Comment: @petey still not working

Comment: @Jabaluza it is not getting checked on mobile devices

Comment: @MaazAli by clicking the label, the radio or both?

Comment: @Jabaluza it is not working on both.

Comment: I think some of your other code is effecting the problem. As you can see, it works on a fiddle with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/qsj08u95/

Comment: @Jabaluza as i explained. it does work on windows using all the main browsers. but it is not on the mobile devices. I tried everything but everything seems to be okay...

Comment: @MaazAli the fiddle works on android and ios too. So, the problem is caused by some other code.

Comment: thanks @Jabaluza  I found the problem which was not with the html as you describe

Comment: In fact, I didn't point on the HTML but good to hear you found it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I found the problem. which was not with this HTML code. there was another **Div** with **P** tag which was over floating the **radio box's Div** after fixing the other **div** it starts working.